# Passing username and password via a single shell command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script, oracle-linux

The command I am running failed to enter the password correctly

```
sudo ssh username@servername "echo test  test| dsmadmc"
```

And I get this error:

```
IBM Spectrum Protect  
Command Line Administrative Interface - Version, Release, Level 7.0
(c) Copyright by IBM Corporation and other(s) 1990. All Rights Reserved.

Enter your user id:  
ANS1051I Invalid user id or password
ANS1051I Invalid user id or password
ANS8023E Unable to establish a session with a server.
ANS1051I Invalid user id or password
ANS8002I Highest return code was 137.
```

I am trying to have a single command where I can pass both username and password on to the execution of commands.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you sure you can pass the username and password to the dsmadmc command on standard input? Also, you're sending "test test" as the username. you might want `"{ echo test; echo test; } | dsmadmc"` to give the username and password on separate lines.

Comment: I got the same error after using below suggest ones

"{ echo test; echo test; } | dsmadmc"

IBM Spectrum Protect
Command Line Administrative Interface - Version 8, Release 1, Level 7.0
(c) Copyright by IBM Corporation and other(s) 1990, 2019. All Rights Reserved.

Enter your user id:  
ANS1051I Invalid user id or password
ANS1051I Invalid user id or password
ANS8023E Unable to establish session with server.
ANS1051I Invalid user id or password

Comment: Edit your question;  Please do not use comments.  Your question as it’s currently written is confusing.

Comment: You might have to use a tool like [tag:expect]

Comment: If at all possible, you should use pre-shared keys instead of passwords, especially for automation. Then you could simply specify the keyfile: `ssh <username>@<server> -i <keyfile>.pub`.